# How to run Chrome/Chromium extension from terminal [LINE extension]

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

## Are there any other ways to open LINE chromium extension from terminal?

This is [LINE extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc)

I can open LINE extension manually (Launch Chromium then click LINE icon) without any problems.

However I want to open LINE extension from terminal.

LINE version 2.3.7

LINE ID: ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc

I've tried

```bsh
# These commands will open chromium
# with "Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or unreadable"
$ chromium --load-extension="/home/$myusername/.config/chromium/Extensions/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc"
$ chromium --load-extension="/home/$myusername/.config/chromium/Extensions/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/2.3.7_0/"
```

```bsh
# chrome://version
Chromium    80.0.3987.149 (Developer Build) built on Debian 10.3, running on Debian 10.3 (64-bit)
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 8.0.426.27
Flash   (Disabled)
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization --no-default-browser-check --disable-pings --media-router=0 --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --disable-webrtc-apm-in-audio-service --file-url-path-alias=/gen=/usr/lib/chromium/gen
Executable Path /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
Profile Path    /home/$myusername/.config/chromium/Default
```

```bsh
# LINE EXTENSION
$ xprop
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 1
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 3326342
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified location: 592, 250
        program specified minimum size: 1 by 1
WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "LINE"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "LINE"
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =    Icon (16 x 16):
     ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░ 
    ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒░      ░▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒          ▒▒▒
    ▒▒░          ░▒▒
    ▒▒  ░ ░░ ░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒  ░ ░░░░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒  ░░░░ ░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒░          ░▒▒
    ▒▒▒░        ░▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒░      ░▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░  ▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░
     ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░ 

    Icon (16 x 16):
     ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░ 
    ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒░      ░▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒          ▒▒▒
    ▒▒░          ░▒▒
    ▒▒  ░ ░░ ░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒  ░ ░░░░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒  ░░░░ ░░░  ▒▒
    ▒▒░          ░▒▒
    ▒▒▒░        ░▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒░      ░▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░  ▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░
     ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░ 


_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR(CARDINAL) = 2
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 41943062, 41943063
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "pop-up"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "crx_ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc", "Chromium"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 5518
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "ASUSDOGE"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
```

[Debian 10]

---

I've read

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063331/how-to-install-google-chrome-extensions-though-terminal

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193369/run-chrome-extensions-using-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

Well, to open LINE extension in it's own window, you can call chromium and use `--app`.

```
chromium --app=chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html
```

Comment: This even works with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc version 3.0.1 !

Comment: Works except on chromebook with garcon-url-handler.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this.

Normally when click LINE icon on chromium, LINE has its own window, not depends on chromium (I can close chromium after I open LINE).

However I can open LINE on chromium browser with URL address:

```bsh
chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html#popout
```

So now I can open LINE from terminal with

```bsh
$ chromium chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html#popout
```

But this will open LINE on chromium browser, not on its own window. So I'll consider this as an alternative ways, and this question is still UNSOLVED.

Comment: With https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc version 3.0.1 just gives white window.